# How to get the kth term in N Combination R

Tags: java, math, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

How do I get the `kth` combination in`NCR`. without iterating through all possible outcomes. e.g. say I have `3C2` for `3` positions and `2`identical-items. I am aware it's `[011]`,`[101]` and `[110]`. how do I get e.g. the 2nd term(**k=1**) which is `[101]` using a method?

**constraints**(`R < N` `k >= 0` and `k < P` where `P = NCR`).

> **NB:**`[101]` is the 2nd term(*in ascending/lexicographical order*) because `011` **=** 3,`101` **=** 5 ,`110` **=** 6
>   in decimal. so basically the goal is to get what number **k** in **NCR** is,
>   because every **kth** output from **NCR** can be represented as a number.

Comment: What are the constraints on N and R and can you also post the whole question, that would help us to come with an algorithm of efficient time complexity that will work in ur case.

Comment: N and R can be any number but R < N. an example question would be to find the the 4th(**k=3**) term in 4 Combination 2  :=> `[0011]`,`[0101]`,`[0110]`,`[1001]`,`[1010]`,`[1100]` which equals `[1001]`

Comment: Ohk and what is the constraint on K , like is 1 <= K <= 10^5, something like that ?

Comment: well k < 4C2 which equals 6, so k should be less than P if NCR = P

Comment: It does not really make sense to speak about the "k-th" combination. There are many different sets that have a cardinality of nCr and they are not ordered. So you need first to select one representation and to define an order on it.

Comment: @Henry what I need is to be able to get the kth index from all possible arrangements of say 2 identical items in a space of 4. obviously that's 4C2 possible ways now I want to pick the kth outcome out of all the ways

Comment: Yes, but what makes `[101]` the second? why is it not the third? And why is it not represented as `(0,2)` (i.e. take two of the numbers from 0 to 2)?

Comment: I agree with @Henry

Comment: because if you directly convert e.g. the initial example to decimal `[0011]`,`[0101]`,`[0110]`,`[1001]`,`[1010]`,`[1100]` you would get 3,5,6,9,10,12

Comment: so basically it's in ascending order if you like or all kth terms in any N combination R can be a number all I want is how to get the kth number in any NCR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity is O(kn), space is O(n)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //n = 4, r = 2, k = 3
    int[] ret1 = getKthPermutation(4, 2, 3);
    //ret1 is [1,0,0,1]

    //n = 3, r = 2, k = 1
    int[] ret2 = getKthPermutation(3, 2, 1);
    //ret2 is [1,0,1]
}

static int[] getKthPermutation(int n, int r, int k) {
    int[] array = new int[n];
    setLastN(array, r, 1);

    int lastIndex = n - 1;
    for(int count = 0; count < k; count++) {

        int indexOfLastOne = findIndexOfLast(array, lastIndex, 1);
        int indexOfLastZero = findIndexOfLast(array, indexOfLastOne, 0);
        array[indexOfLastOne] = 0;
        array[indexOfLastZero] = 1;

        //shortcut: swap the part after indexOfLastZero to keep them sorted
        int h = indexOfLastZero + 1;
        int e = lastIndex;
        while(h < e) {
            int temp = array[h];
            array[h] = array[e];
            array[e] = temp;
            h++;
            e--;
        }

    }

    return array;
}

//starting from `from`, and traveling the array forward, find the first `value` and return its index.
static int findIndexOfLast(int[] array, int from, int value) {
    for(int i = from; i > -1; i--)
        if(array[i] == value) return i;
    return -1;
}

//set the last n elements of an array to `value`
static void setLastN(int[] array, int n, int value){
    for(int i = 0, l = array.length - 1; i < n; i++)
        array[l - i] = value;
}
```

This is an adaption of the very typical "find the kth permation" algorithm.

I will try to explain the general idea (yours is a special case as there are only two types of elements: 0 and 1).
Lets say I have `[2,1,6,4,7,5]`. What is the next smallest permutation that is bigger than the current one? Why do I concern the next smallest permutation bigger than current one? Because if you start with the smallest permutation `[1,2,4,5,6,7]` and you repeat the action (find the smallest bigger than current) k times, you will find k+1 th smallest permutation.

Now, since the one I am looking for needs to be bigger than current one, I need to increment the current one. To keep the incrementation as small as possible, I am going to try to modify 5 (last one). Now, I cannot just change 5 to a random value, I can only swap it with some digit before it.

If I swap 5 with a bigger number before it, say 7, then I will get `[2,1,6,4,5,7]`, which is smaller than current one. Now obviously I need to swap 5 with some smaller digit before it, but which one? If I swap 5 with 2, I get `[5,1,6,4,7,2]`, this increment is too big. I need to swap 5 with a "lower digit" to keep the increment as small as possible. Thats leads us to find the first(lowest) digit (from right to left) that is smaller than 5. In this case I would need to swap 5 with 4 and get `[2,1,6,5,7,4]`. This way, I can make the impact of "swap" small. Now the prefix is decided `[2,1,6,5`. There is no smaller prefix. We need to deal with suffix `7,4]`. Clearly, if we sort the suffix and make it `4,7]`, then we are done.

In our case, there are two differences:
1. we need to swap the last 1, because you cannot make the permutation bigger by swapping the a zero with any digit before it.
2. we can always sort the suffix using a shortcut as shown in the code. I will leave it to you:)

Comment: Wow!!!!...Kudos

Comment: Hi @Wang Sheng could you help with converting back  (a reversal of the algorithm) thanks

Comment: you mean, given a permutation and that it is the kth smallest permutation, find the 1th smallest permutation?

Comment: No I mean `static int[] getKthPermutation(int n, int r, int k)` reversal i.e. 
  `static int[] getK(int n, int r,int[] KthPermutation)`

Comment: in your application, is `n` and `r` fixed value? or do they change very often? Given the same `n` and `r`, how many times do you need to run the reversal function? I am asking because i wonder if you can intermediate result.

Comment: they change very often but frequently `n` is always < 182

Comment: sorry I made a mistake above.  ... `static int[] getK(int n, int r,int[] KthPermutation)` should be `static int getK(int n, int r,int[] KthPermutation)`

Comment: hmmm, one way i can think of (you may have figured out), is to extract the logic from `getKthPermutation` and make `getNextPermutation`. And then repeatedly call `getNextPermutation` and compare the result with the target permutation, stop until you match.  And in the meantime, keep track of how many times you have caled `getNextPermutation`.

Comment: Hmmm alright...thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct when you say:

> because every kth output from NCR can be represented as a number.

There is a bijection from the set of integers `1 to # of combs/perms` to the entire set of combs/perms. Finding the specific index of a particular comb/perm is sometimes referred to as getting the rank. According to the example that you have in your question, these are ordinary permutations. Moreover when you mention ***ascending order***, you are referring to the [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

It is a straightforward exercise in counting to obtain the *n<sup>th</sup>* ordinary permutation of a given set. We first need to obtain the total number of permutations using the well established formula:

```
P(n, r) = n! / (n - r)!
```

This next part is the key observation that allows us to quickly obtain each element of our target permutation.

> If we look at all permutations of our set of *n* choose *r*, there will be *n* groups that are only different by a permutation of the *n* elements.

For example, if we look at the *first* two group of the permutations of `[0 1 2 3] choose 3`, we have:

```
      [,0] [,1] [,2]
 [0,]    0    1    2
 [1,]    0    1    3
 [2,]    0    2    1
 [3,]    0    2    3
 [4,]    0    3    1
 [5,]    0    3    2
 [6,]    1    0    2
 [7,]    1    0    3
 [8,]    1    2    0
 [9,]    1    2    3
[10,]    1    3    0
[11,]    1    3    2
```

Note that the last permutations are simply the first 6 permutations of the set `[1 0 2 3]`.. that is, 0 is mapped to 1, 1 is mapped to 0, and the final 2 elements are mapped to themselves.

This pattern continues as we move to the right only instead of *n* identical groups, we will get *n - 1* similar groups for the second column, *n -2* for the third, and so on.

So to determine the first element of our permutation, we need to determine the *1<sup>st</sup>* group. We do that by simply dividing the number of permutations by *n*. For our example above of permutations of 4 choose 3, if we were looking for the *15<sup>th</sup>* permutation, we have the following for the first element:

```
Possible indices : [0 1 2 3]
P(4, 3) = 24
24 / 4 = 6 (elements per group)
15 / 6 = 2 (integer division) 2 means the 3rd element here (base zero)
```

Now that we have used the *3<sup>rd</sup>* element, we need to remove it from our array of possible indices. How do we get the next element?

> Easy, we get our next **subindex** by subtracting the product of the group we just found and the elements per group from our original index.

```
Possible indices : [0 1 3]
Next index is 15 - 6 * 2 = 3
```

Now, we just repeat this until we have filled all entries:

```
Possible indices : [0 1 3]
Second element
6 / 3 = 2 (elements per group)
3 / 2 = 1
Next index is 3 - 3 * 1 = 0

Possible indices : [0 3]
Third element
2 / 2 = 1
0 / 1 = 0
```

So our *15<sup>th</sup>* element is : `[2 1 0]`

Here is a `C++` implementation that should be pretty easy to translate to `Java`:

```
double NumPermsNoRep(int n, int k) {
    double result = 1;
    double i, m = n - k;

    for (i = n; i > m; --i)
        result *= i;

    return result;
}

std::vector<int> nthPermutation(int n, int r, double myIndex) {
    int j = 0, n1 = n;
    double temp, index1 = myIndex;
    std::vector<int> res(r);

    temp = NumPermsNoRep(n, r);
    std::vector<int> indexVec(n);
    std::iota(indexVec.begin(), indexVec.end(), 0);

    for (int k = 0; k < r; ++k, --n1) {
        temp /= n1;
        j = (int) std::trunc(index1 / temp);
        res[k] = indexVec[j];
        index1 -= (temp * (double) j);
        indexVec.erase(indexVec.begin() + j);
    }
}
```

These concepts extends to other types of combinatorial problems, such as finding the *n<sup>th</sup>* combination, or permutation with repetition, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String lexicographicPermutation(String str, long n) {
    final long[] factorials = { 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600 };

    n--;
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        long fact = factorials[arr.length - i - 2];
        long p = i + n / fact;

        n %= fact;

        for (int j = i + 1; j <= p; j++)
            swap(arr, i, j);
    }

    return new String(arr);
}

private static void swap(char[] arr, int i, int j) {
    char tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

You can replace `STR` with required string. In the given example, **1st** permutation is `"abcdefghijklm"` (this is a string with 13 chars), **13!st** permutation is reverse string `"mlkjihgfedcba"` and **100st** permutation is `"abcfklgmeihjd"`.

To realise this soulution just google [Factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system). This is a **key** to solve this problem. This is a [Project Euler: Problem 24](https://projecteuler.net/problem=24).

***Demo:***

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    System.out.println(lexicographicPermutation("110", i));

1 - 110
2 - 101
3 - 110
4 - 101
5 - 011
6 - 011

for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    System.out.println(lexicographicPermutation("abc", i));

1 - abc
2 - acb
3 - bac
4 - bca
5 - cab
6 - cba
```

Comment: down voting because this doesn't solve the problem e.g. if `String STR = "110"` the kth term of my problem is always "110" according to your solution e.g. `System.out.println(lexicographicPermutation(3));` @ `main(String[] args)`

Comment: @LiNKeR Do look at `Demo` I gave. My example gives absolute correct answer.