# Find K'th position of nCm

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

**Question:**

Given 3 integers n, m, k ***(n, m ≤ 10^4; k ≤ 10^9)***. Find the K'th position of nCm.

**Example:**

N = 7, M = 3, K = 6.

The first 6 7C3 permutations are:

- 1 2 3
- 1 2 4
- 1 2 5
- 1 2 6
- 1 2 7
- 1 3 4

So the answer would be **1 3 4**

**P/S:** I only know how to solve this problem using brute force, which takes O(N*K). Is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the kth term in N Combination R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848026/16757174)

Comment: @kcsquared The best answer to the question you linked explains how to find the kth permutation, not the kth combination. Then it ends with the encouraging sentence *"These concepts extends to other types of combinatorial problems, such as finding the nth combination, or permutation with repetition, etc."*.

Comment: Search for "unrank" combination.